# What is the correct type of this of 's'

Tags: python

Hi guys going trough some python code, and i came across this line (if statement line).After i check the type of 's' after the statement ,it is still of 'str type'.How does int(s[0])%2==0) affect 's'.Does it slice 's' first, and then convert the obtained value to int type?.the relevant part of the code:

```
values = []
for i in range(1000, 3001):
    s = str(i)
    if (int(s[0])%2==0): 
        #print type(s) #type str
        values.append(s)
print ",".join(values)
```

Comment: Why would the type of `s` change if you haven't changed `s`???

Comment: Just because you wrote `int(s[0])` does not mean that `s` is now an int—or that any part of it is. It's a string, since you casted it with `s = str(i)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `int(x)` it will take whatever the value of `x` and convert it into an `integer`. It doesn't change the type of the variable `x`.

This is called Casting and you can get more information [here](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/interesting-casting-in-python)

If you don't include the casting operation there, it will result in error as you are trying to do modulus operation on a string value, will will be an illegal operation.

So you are taking the value which s[0] holds, converts / casts that into an integer and then perform the Modulus operation.

Comment: Python doesn't have typecasts: you aren't simply treating `x` as an integer, you are creating a completely new object using the value of `x` as the value of the new object.

Comment: @chepner Casting is a general term used in programming and I used it. Of course I can go to system level operations which are being performed in here, but didn't see the need for that....

Comment: I agree with chepner, casting is not the correct term here since there is a new object rather than changed interpretation of a present object. Type conversion which you wrote in you first paragraph feels more suitable.

Comment: Allright, let's call it Type Conversion

Answer (score 0):

Your code will take in a number, for example `1782`, and will convert it to a string so that you can take the first character from the number. Thus, we will get `"1"` from the aforementioned number. Then, it converts to an integer so that it can calculate module `%` on the number, returning `1` if the number is odd, and `0` if it is even. Thus, `if num == 0` or in pseudocode `if num is even`, we proceed.

Effectively, thus code will enter the `if` statement if the first digit of the number `i` is even.

Answer (score 0):

If you had not casted int(s[0]) you would not be able to check if the first character in the string s is even (which is what int(s[0])%2==0 is doing).  So try it: take off the int and you will get a type error.